# SonataAdminBundle - rewrite action button teplates in config.yml

Tags: symfony, templates, sonata-admin

I customized templates of action buttons (show, edit and delete) and currently am calling them from within Admin class.

```
->add('_action', 'actions', array(
            'actions' => array(
                'show' => array('template' => 'IndexBundle:Admin:action/show.html.twig'),
                'edit' => array('template' => 'IndexBundle:Admin:action/edit.html.twig'),
                'delete' => array('template' => 'IndexBundle:Admin:action/delete.html.twig')
            )
        ));
```

But instead of defining templates in each Admin I would like that these templates would rewrite default ones in config file. Unfortunately, documentation does not mention rewriting default action template globally. Is there a way?

```
sonata_admin:
    templates:
        ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite any part of any bundle, if define new files in '*app*' directory.

For your sample, if u just want to rewrite default button templates, u can do this:

```
{# app/Resources/SonataAdminBundle/views/CRUD/list__action_edit.html.twig #}

{% if admin.isGranted('EDIT', object) and admin.hasRoute('edit') %}
<a href="{{ admin.generateObjectUrl('edit', object) }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-default edit_link" title="{{ 'action_edit'|trans({}, 'SonataAdminBundle') }}">
    {# icon was here #}
    {{ 'action_edit'|trans({}, 'SonataAdminBundle') }}
</a>
{% endif %}
```

Use:

- **list__action_delete.html.twig** for delete button
- **list__action_edit.html.twig for** editing button
- **list__action_show.html.twig** for show action button

Other templates u can found in */vendor/sonata-project/admin-bundle/Resources/views/CRUD/* directory

PS. do not forget to clear cache.

Comment: Added correctly named teplates in `app/Resources/views/CRUD/` directory and cleared the cache and it didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: U forget 'SonataAdminBundle' in directory structure. The correct path is 'app/Resources/SonataAdminBundle/views/CRUD/'